# Marking eBay order as shipper via API returns 'GetSellerTransactionsResponseType incompatible with CompleteSaleResponseType' error

Tags: java, ebay-api

I need to mark eBay order as shipped via eBay API.

Have a method:

```
public void ShippEbayOrder(EbayOrder ebayOrder)
{
    string Developer = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["EbayProductionDevID"];
    string Application = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["EbayProductionAppID"];
    string Certificate = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["EbayProductionCertID"];
    string eBayToken = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["EbayProductionUserToken"];
    string SoapApiServerUrl = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["EbayProductionApiServerUrl"];
    string SignInUrl = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["EbayProductionSignInUrl"];
    string EPSServerUrl = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["EbayProductionEPSUrl"];

    var ebayService = GetebayService();

    CompleteSaleRequestType completeSaleRequestType = new CompleteSaleRequestType();
    completeSaleRequestType.Version = version;

    if (ebayOrder.ContainsOrderType == EbayOrder.OrderType.Transaction)
    {
        completeSaleRequestType.TransactionID = ebayOrder.SourceOrderId;
        completeSaleRequestType.ItemID = ebayOrder.ItemsInfo[0].SourceItemId;
    }
    else
        completeSaleRequestType.OrderID = ebayOrder.SourceOrderId;

    completeSaleRequestType.Shipped = true;
    completeSaleRequestType.ShippedSpecified = true;
    CompleteSaleResponseType completeSaleResponseType = ebayService.CompleteSale(completeSaleRequestType);
```

But when code calls CompleteSale method, it throws an exeption:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.ebay.domain.apisoap.pres.service.hosting.soap.basecomponents.GetSellerTransactionsResponseType incompatible with com.ebay.domain.apisoap.pres.service.hosting.soap.basecomponents.CompleteSaleResponseType
```

Who can help me? Thank you!

Comment: What does `ebayService.CompleteSale` return because it clearly is NOT a `CompleteSaleResponseType` we need more information.

Comment: It returns CompleteSaleResponseType object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

right code and method should be:

```
public void ShippEbayOrder(EbayOrder ebayOrder)
    {
        string Developer = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["EbayProductionDevID"];
        string Application = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["EbayProductionAppID"];
        string Certificate = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["EbayProductionCertID"];
        string eBayToken = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["EbayProductionUserToken"];
        string SoapApiServerUrl = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["EbayProductionApiServerUrl"];
        string SignInUrl = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["EbayProductionSignInUrl"];
        string EPSServerUrl = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["EbayProductionEPSUrl"];

        var ebayService = new eBayAPIInterfaceService();

        string version = "551";
        string requestUrl = SoapApiServerUrl + "?callname=CompleteSale&siteid=0"
                            + "&appid=" + Application + "&version=" + version + "&routing=default";
        ebayService.Url = requestUrl;
        ebayService.RequesterCredentials = new CustomSecurityHeaderType();
        ebayService.RequesterCredentials.Credentials = new UserIdPasswordType();
        ebayService.RequesterCredentials.Credentials.AppId = Application;
        ebayService.RequesterCredentials.Credentials.DevId = Developer;
        ebayService.RequesterCredentials.Credentials.AuthCert = Certificate;
        ebayService.RequesterCredentials.eBayAuthToken = eBayToken;

        CompleteSaleRequestType completeSaleRequestType = new CompleteSaleRequestType();
        completeSaleRequestType.Version = version;

        if (ebayOrder.ContainsOrderType == EbayOrder.OrderType.Transaction)
        {
            completeSaleRequestType.TransactionID = ebayOrder.SourceOrderId;
            completeSaleRequestType.ItemID = ebayOrder.ItemsInfo[0].SourceItemId;
        }
        else
            completeSaleRequestType.OrderID = ebayOrder.SourceOrderId;

        completeSaleRequestType.Shipped = true;
        completeSaleRequestType.ShippedSpecified = true;
        CompleteSaleResponseType completeSaleResponseType = ebayService.CompleteSale(completeSaleRequestType);
    }
```